# HttpUrlConnection Response comparison failed

Tags: java, android, response, httpurlconnection

I have simple HttpUrlConnection Post Request. It goes to a php file then looks for data, if data is not there, the php file echos "N", if it is there the php file echose the data.. And in my java code, i use a check to see if the response is "N" before processing the data. But the data is always processed even if the response in N.. this causes the app to crash. Heres my code and logcat error: Please help :)

Java code

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            OutputStream os = null;
            HttpURLConnection con = null;
            String cRE;
            try {

                Log.e("DATA", getArti);

                //constants
                URL url = new URL("http:www.url.com/php/getarticles.php");
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("req", type + ";" + getArti + extraNetworkData);
                String message = jsonObject.toString();

                con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setReadTimeout(10000);
                con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(message.getBytes().length);

                //make some HTTP header nicety
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                con.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

                //open
                con.connect();

                //setup send
                os = new BufferedOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
                os.write(message.getBytes());
                //clean up
                os.flush();

                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    Log.e("RESPONSE STATUS", "ITS HTTP_OK");
                    String line;
                    InputStream iStream = con.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
                    brr.mark(0);
                    while ((line = brr.readLine()) != null) {
                        cRE = line;

                        Log.e("Res", cRE); // RESPONSE

                        if (type.equals("FT")) {

                            String data[] = cRE.split("-");
                            title = data[0];
                            image = data[1];
                            id = data[2];
                            dateNumber = data[3];
                        } else if (type.equals("R")) { // R = REFRESH DATA

                            if(cRE.equals("N")) {

                                Log.e("REQUEST DATA RESPONSE", "R Data = NULL");
                            } else {

                                String data[] = cRE.split("-");
                                title = data[0];
                                image = data[1];
                                id = data[2];
                                dateNumber = data[3];
                            }
                        } else if(cRE.equals("SC")) { // SC = SCROLL DOWN DATA

                            if(cRE.equals("N")) {

                            } else {

                                String data[] = cRE.split("-");
                                title = data[0];
                                image = data[1];
                                id = data[2];
                                dateNumber = data[3];
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    processNetworkData();

                } else {
                    Log.e("RESPONSE ERR", con.getResponseMessage());

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                con.disconnect();
            }
        }

    }).start();
```

php code:

```
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $aDate, $id, $title, $image);

    $ad = "";
    $d = "";
    $tit = "";
    $ima = "";

    if(is_null(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))) {

      echo "N";

    } else {

      /* Fetch value */
      while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

        $ad = $ad ."". "$aDate;";
        $d = $d ."". "$id;";
        $tit = $tit ."". "$title;";
        $ima = $ima ."". "$image;";

        }

        $aDa = substr($ad, 0, -1);
        $aId = substr($d, 0, -1);
        $aTitle = substr($tit, 0, -1);
        $aImage = substr($ima, 0, -1);

        echo "$aTitle-$aImage-$aId-$aDa";

        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
```

Logcat error:

```
11-29 16:17:30.397 17160-31330/com.android.appname E/RESPONSE STATUS: ITS HTTP_OK
11-29 16:17:30.398 17160-31330/com.android.appname E/Res: N       
11-29 16:17:30.399 17160-31330/com.android.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7023
11-29 16:17:30.399 17160-31330/com.android.appname E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.appname, PID: 17160
11-29 16:17:30.399 17160-31330/com.android.appname E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
11-29 16:17:30.399 17160-31330/com.android.appname E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.appname.Pages.Articles.AllArticlesFragment$3.run(AllArticlesFragment.java:302)
11-29 16:17:30.399 17160-31330/com.android.appname E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 2):

the framework can handle ["emptyNess"](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/) for you..

Why get involved in edge cases and all this application level logic when you can configure the View layer to handle 'empty' for you?

You might think about this as a general pattern...

> Server/PHP Input POST Url/parms
>
> Server Output : JSON
>
> Network :: Http
>
> client Async Req/Response Handler
>
> JsonObject --> ViewHolder
>
> ```
>  ViewHolder --> ListView
>
>      ListView configured for "empty" case
> ```

[example of above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997142/how-to-loop-json-array-and-print-the-values-in-listview-android)

Think about a PHP refactor.

IMO, if the  server returns json object where the edge case (empty ) will simply be an empty json.Array inside the Root 'results' ?  That seems easier and good separation of concerns compared to rendering JSON on the client as part of handling the http response.

Testing is easier and cleaner if you remove clients responsibility for taking low level http.response and creating JSON from it.

If you do that, then your client side code can be much shorter/less complicated. ie in android you build the view from the Json returned by PHP.